# how to open multiple urls from richtextbox

Tags: c#

I have this code to open multiple urls from a richtextbox, it works fine, but the problem is that it opens all sites in separate browsers.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     for(int i = 0 ; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length ; i++ )
     {
        Process.Start("http://" + richTextBox1.Lines[i]);
     }
 }
```

Any ideas how I can open the pages like tabs in the same browser?

Comment: With which browser are you experiencing this issue?

Comment: With Firefox browser

Comment: It would depend on the browser.  For example, Chrome opens a new Process for each tab, so theoretically the code above could open them all in the same browser window in different tabs, but Firefox only has 1 process per window regardless of the number of tabs open

Comment: Thanks Saggio , i tried to open them throw Chrome and it works
but how to make it works on FireFox?

Comment: I'm not sure how FireFox handles multiple tabs internally (perhaps by using different threads?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string item in richTextBox1.Lines)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "firefox.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "-new-tab " + item;
            Process.Start(startInfo); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this;

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

The following should work according to the article;

```
firefox.exe -new-tab <url>
```